# Android Support Library Floating Action Button exception

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button

I'm experiencing an odd behaviour regarding `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`. I have googled around a little but found no mention of this kind of error for this component.

This only happens when I build with android `StrictMode` enabled. I get the following exception:

```
CoordinatorLayout﹕ Default behavior class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$a could not be instantiated. Did you forget a default constructor?
java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$a; no empty constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.a(CoordinatorLayout.java:503)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:579)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2586)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2189)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1352)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1535)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6364)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeN
```

This, however does not make my application to crash or throws any visible error. It's thrown each time the activity which has the FAB is created, but the FAB renders and works perfectly fine. If I click on it, it does what the `onClickListener` says it should do.

This is are my Android Support Library dependencies, in my `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

And this is how I use the FAB in my xml layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home_toolbar_wallet"
        android:name="my.fragment.class"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    (...)
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/home_floating_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_18dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/action_button_margin"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/home_toolbar_wallet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

In case you are wondering, this is how I enable `StrictMode`:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .detectAll()
    .penaltyLog();
if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
    builder.penaltyFlashScreen();
}
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(builder.build());
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectAll()
    .penaltyLog()
    .build());
```

Anyone has encountered with this?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178339 ?

Comment: Thanks I came up with exactly that and was going to make an update! @Distwo answer is correct! I've tried it and solved my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be due to proguard obfuscating your code.
Have you tried to add this rule to your proguard rules?

```
-keepclassmembers class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$Behavior { public <init>(); }
```

Comment: I had this issue using a custom `Behavior` on a layout and @distwo was totally correct. Proguard was culling the 'unused' constructor. Interesting that AS and Proguard knows not to cull `View` constructors but doesn't know to do the same for `Behaviour` constructors...